# Looking for ideal calibration standards for UV / visible fluorescence

Tags: visible-light, measurements, experimental-technique, luminosity, fluorescence

I am attempting to measure the fluorescence timing distribution (how much light is emitted over time from initial excitation) of a substance and I would like to use a solid calibrated sample (some material that has a very well known fluorescence timing distribution, not in solution) to make sure that my experimental setup is able to measure that same quantity.

Ideally we are looking to irradiate the substance with VUV light and measure fluorescence in the UV and visible.

Is there any company you can recommend that provides with such products, or any substance/material that would do the trick?

The only calibration standards I could find so far were for x-ray fluorescence which is way out of our range.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use a material in solution or a solid ?
Maybe, organic dyes (2-Aminopurine in water) can be useful for your purpose. Never used in my case, but it seems to be well documented [here](http://www.iss.com/fluorescence/software/vinci.html).
In solution, if your concentration of dyes is low enough, you can expect a fluorescence lifetime similar to the literature. In solid, it's more complicated in general.

Comment: Yes, it is actually solids I am going to work with, which makes it a bit challenging. Thanks for the answer, I edited my question so that solid samples are explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Try to take a look on LiCAF, a laser gain media doped with rare earth ions [here](https://www.rp-photonics.com/rare_earth_doped_gain_media.html). Good luck,